# flickr API, getClusterPhotos with license filter

Tags: api, flickr

I am getting a collection of photos via this flickr API:

description: http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.tags.getClusterPhotos.html
example: http://www.flickr.com/services/api/explore/flickr.tags.getClusterPhotos

I see no option to include the license parameter on the API query and I thus get copyrighted images returned, which I do not want. I see that I can get the license info by calling flickr.photos.getInfo on each individual image, but this will be quite time consuming. Are there any other methods to get a collection of photos from a tag cluster with a particular license?

Answer (score 3):

License is one of the parameters listed in their api here:
http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.search.html

I would try just using the id's from the results listed here in their return:
http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.licenses.getInfo.html

for example: 
&license=4

Comment: The link you provided is for flickr.photos.search. I need to set the license for flickr.tags.getClusterPhotos. The problem with retrieving the license individually for each photo is that I end up with only two or three useable images out of the pool of images returned. What I need is a pool of creative commons tag cluster images.

Answer (score 0):

It may be better to use "flickr.photos.search" instead. You can search for a specific tag and license (there is no need to do a second call on each image).

https://www.flickr.com/services/api/explore/flickr.photos.search